# How to iterate over a column headers and row values in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For the dataframe df, I would like to accomplish the following: (1) Iterate through column headers and change every header with "Vol" in it, to Vol_Adj, and (2) Iterate through the values that correspond to those headers, and divide them by the corresponding values (for each row) from the column with the header "eTIV"

Here is what I tried:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if 'Vol' in col:
        df[col] = df.col / df.eTIV
        df= df.rename(index=str, columns={col: col + "_Adj"})
```

I am getting the following error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'.

When breaking apart the code, this works separately:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
```

And so does this:

```
df['one'] = df.one / df.five
```

As does this:

```
df= df.rename(index=str, columns={"three": "three_Adj"})
```

But it these commands do not integrate in the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
for key,value in df.iteritems():
    if 'Vol' in key:
        key = key + '_Adj'
        value = value / df.five
        print(key,value)
```